# How to set up transaction with myBatis and Spring

Tags: spring, transactions, mybatis

I am trying set up transaction but without success. 
Here is my code:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource">
   .......
   <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-configuration.xml" />
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

---

```
@Transactional
private void prcessTransaction(...) {
 delete(...);
 //insert:
 for(Item item: itemList){
   insert(item)
 }
}

<delete id="delete" parameterType="map">
    delete from .....
  </delete>

<insert id="insert" parameterType="Item">
    insert into ....
  </insert>
```

It looks like that prcessTransaction method is not only one transaction but sets of multiple transactions.

I am using Spring 3.0.5, myBatis 3.0.4, mybatis-spring-1.0.1, Tomcat 7.0.19, Oracle     11.1.0.6.0

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you calling `getSqlMapClientTemplate` (the Spring API) or are you issuing the iBATIS calls using the iBATIS API?

Comment: I am using iBatis calls.

Comment: Does your database support transactions?

Comment: Sure, I am using Oracle 11.1.0.6.0

Answer (score 3):

Putting @transactional on a private method looks problematic, [the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) says:

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional.

The same section has this aside:

> **Method visibility and @Transactional**
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem, but in a more complex environment where we have 2 databases with their own transaction manager each. The only way we got it to work was to specify the transaction manager instance on the `@Transactional("transactionManager")` annotation.

It works, though I'm left unsatisfied as I don't understand why we need to explicitly specify the transaction manager on the annotation.